# CreateDocumentQuery throws exception when used with LINQ, fine with SQL

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to retrieve a single entity stored in my Azure DocumentDb. I have discovered that my code *only* works when I supply the query by SQL, like the below:

```
var query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM UserDetail u WHERE u.id = '{0}'", id);
return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(_selfLink, query).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

However using a LINQ expression, as in the following two examples, it fails with an exception:

```
// EXCEPTION
return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(_selfLink).Where(u => u.Id.ToString() == id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

// EXCEPTION
return (from u in _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(_selfLink)
    where u.Id.ToString() == id
    select u).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

The rather monstrous stack trace of the exception raised is:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Unhandled expression type: 'Call'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarLambda(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.SQLTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.HandleMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, QueryType defaultQueryType, QueryType& queryType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression expression, QueryType defaultQueryType, QueryType& queryType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteAllAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.<GetEnumeratorTAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Cherish.Domain.Repositories.Implementation.DocumentRepository`1.FindById(String id) in \\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Cherish\Cherish.Domain\Repositories\Implementation\DocumentRepository.cs:line 82
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Unhandled expression type: 'Call'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarLambda(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.SQLTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.HandleMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, QueryType defaultQueryType, QueryType& queryType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression expression, QueryType defaultQueryType, QueryType& queryType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteAllAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.<GetEnumeratorTAsync>d__10.MoveNext()<---
```

For reference, this is the UserDetail class (irrelevant properties and methods removed):

```
public class UserDetail : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fn")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ln")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contribs")]
    public IList<ContributorRelation> Contributors { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I can use the SQL-format method, however as a personal preference I would like to use Lambdas, and am at a loss to understand why my code does not work as it should. Do I need to do some other type of type coersion from Guid?

Comment: Looks like it's a "correction-in-progress" bug : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b6db0dc-75da-45c2-86bf-aa325685232e/querying-on-guid-fields-in-documentdb?forum=AzureDocumentDB

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Many thanks - that seems to be the bug. Hopefully the update will be released soon. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to the `ToString` method is not supported inside linq queries. Try parsing the id to guid and do a simple equality like this:

```
return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(_selfLink).Where(u => u.Id == Guid.Parse(id)).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```